# Removing old commits from github project

Tags: git, github, version-control

I made a bad commit and uploaded a broken folder (its unclickable). I've followed a few tutorials but honestly think they did more harm than good.

I can't even do git log anymore because it says

"fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'"

I just want to go back 2 commits and act as if I never pushed anything. What is the easiest way to go about doing this? I think my local repo has been messed up due to trying to follow guide's online.

Comment: try `git log --all`, Instead of `git log`